# How to use java compareTo() on 2 objects conditionally?

Tags: java, compareto

I have for exam to compare 2 Student objects based on average marks if 2 students are on same level of education. What to return outside if statement?

```
public int compareTo(Student o) {

if(this.getLevel() == o.getLevel()) {
    if(this.getAverage() > o.getAverage()) {
        return 1;
    } else if(this.getAverage() < o.getAverage()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
} 

}
```

Comment: How should we know? We don't even know how your class `Student` is structured.

Comment: Does your requirement state anything about how to compare two `Student`s whose levels are different?

Comment: @user7 - Noticed that after I posted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, compare the levels, and if the result is `0`, compare the averages:

```
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    int result = Integer.compare(this.getLevel(), o.getLevel());
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Integer.compare(this.getAverage(), o.getAverage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

There's also a more advanced way to do this using the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface from Java 8+

```
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getLevel)
                     .thenComparingInt(Student::getAverage)
                     .compare(this, o);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the levels. If that are ints:

```
return Integer.compare(getLevel(), o.getLevel());
```

Entire code:

```
int comparison = Integer.compare(getLevel(), o.getLevel());
if (comparison == 0) {
    comparison = Integer.compare(getAverage(), o.getAverage());
}
return comparison;
```